# Code behind for UI? MouseOver issues

Tags: wpf

Is code behind in WPF for UI related things really ugly?
I'm trying to achieve similar effect to Visual Studio Panels (something like sample in WPF Unleashed book). 
I want to change Grid Visibility to Visible when mouse enter into the button "solutionManagerPanel". It works however when my mouse enter into this Grid, it's visibility changes to hidden.

Below is code in xaml:

```
<Grid Grid.Column="2" Background="Gray" Visibility="{Binding ElementName=solutionManagerPanel, Path=IsMouseOver, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}">

                <Grid.Resources>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Grid}">
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </Grid.Resources>
```

Is there any simple way to do this in XAML or can I write event handling code-behind for this? Wouldn't this violate "clean, MVVM code rules"?

Comment: WHat makes you think it's ugly? There's nothing in MVVM that says "code-behind is forbidden"... sometimes it's the right way to do things (as long as it's purely related to the UI)

Comment: well thank you ;) It seems I've read badly written article telling code behind is always bad : P

Comment: Another option is to use attached behaviors, which encapsulate your event's logic into its own class, that can be referenced from XAML. See [Introduction to Attached Behaviors](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28959/Introduction-to-Attached-Behaviors-in-WPF).